# How to pull data matching from all tabs in the google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have an spreadsheets with 50+ tabs. I would like to pull data match by keyword as sheet name & row number from all tabs.

It's possible by query with specific tab name, but when there is lot of tabs, how to recall from all tabs instated to re-write all tab names in query?

[image]

[Worksheet demo:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eQLiCTXbMfjWO-6_lRGNnQHTg2mtj_dDwpjaAGgrT7w/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your `Expected Result` sheet doesn't make sense. Which column is your input and what would be your desired output?

Comment: Output explained in sheet sir

Comment: Yes, at least you must create a list of all tabs name to cells in expected result tab (otherwise need AppScript coding to collect those tab names). Formula can't iterate tabs automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Updated Solution:***

```
=let(Δ,arrayformula(split(tocol(reduce(wraprows(,columns(A:Z),),to_text(tocol(B3:B,1)),lambda(a,c,{a;let(Σ,indirect("'"&c&"'!A:Z"),if(len(Σ),Σ&"|"&substitute(c,"-","")&"|"&row(Σ),))})),1),"|")),
     Ξ,let(Γ,wraprows(,3,),reduce(Γ,sequence(index(match(2,1/(A3:A<>"")))),lambda(a,c,{a;ifna(filter(Δ,index(Δ,,1)=index(A3:A,c)),Γ)}))),
     unique(filter(substitute(Ξ,"","-"),index(Ξ,,1)<>"")))
```

[image]

Comment: Absolutely perfect! But getting the wrong tab name in the output while the table name is in date format.

Comment: Do test out the updated answer in your sheet and let us know...

Comment: Check `Cell K3` for the fix.

Comment: Added `indirect` function to all the ranges within the formula. so you can now move the formula without messing up the range reference alignment.

Comment: Just not have the blank cells b/w keywords in Column_A and the formula works normal & doesnt need to be modified.

Comment: I've changed it & now you  can see what I meant by having the keywords in one file with no random empty cells in between them

Comment: Dear i face another issue, for example, Col B with an sheet name, that is not the actual sheet name, then the result is error :(

Comment: the formula does not accommodate non-existent tab names. use/enter valid tab names only

Comment: But if a tab is deleted, how do I know which tab is deleted in likee 100 tabs?

Comment: As  Harun24hr said in the above comments, you can search for apps script codes which you can use to pull & auto-update all the active tabs list.